# Cannot stop Javascript loop in carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need my thumbnail slide (part of my carousel) to stop on the last thumbnail instead of looping. I changed the parameters for loop to false but nothing seems to work.

I tried **infinite: false,** and **infiniteLoop: false**. It stills show more thumbnail after reaching the last one. The mystery is that it does not quite loop forever. It continues after the last thumbnail for 8 thumbnails only.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        //  wrap all thumbs in a <div> for the 3x3 grid
        $div = null;
        $('#thumbs').children().each(function (i) {
            /*if ( i % 8 == 0) {
                $div = $( '<div />' );
                $div.appendTo( '#thumbs' );
            }*/
            $(this).appendTo($div);
            $(this).addClass('itm' + i);
            $(this).click(function () {
                $('#images').trigger('slideTo', [i, 0, true]);
            });
        });
        $('#thumbs img.itm0').addClass('selected');

        $(document).ready(function () {
            if (currentWindowSize >= 0 && currentWindowSize <= 768) {
                var x = $(window).width();
                var y = $(window).height();
                var a = x / 2;
                var b = y / 2;

                $(".caroufredsel_wrapper").css('width', a);
                $(".caroufredsel_wrapper").css('height', b);

                //$('.caroufredsel_wrapper').width(400, a);
                //$('.caroufredsel_wrapper').height(200, b);
                //$("#images").css('width', a);
                //$("#images").css('height', b);
            }
        });
        //  the big-image carousel
        $('#images').carouFredSel({
            direction: 'up',
            circular: false,
            infinite: false,
            infiniteLoop: false,
            //width: 656,
            height: 492,
            items: 1,
            auto: false,
            prev: '#prev .images',
            next: '#next .images',
            scroll: {
                fx: 'directscroll',
                onBefore: function () {
                    var pos = $(this).triggerHandler('currentPosition');
                    $('#thumbs img').removeClass('selected');
                    $('#thumbs img.itm' + pos).addClass('selected');

                    var page = Math.floor(pos / 9);
                    $('#thumbs').trigger('', page);
                }
            }
        });

        //  the thumbnail-carousel
        $('#thumbs').carouFredSel({
            direction: 'up',
            circular: false,
            infinite: false,
            infiniteLoop: false,
            width: 80,
            height: 492,
            items: 1,
            align: false,
            auto: false,
            prev: '#prev .thumbs',
            next: '#next .thumbs'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The easyest way i've found to do this is to, outside the loop, count how many slides you have so you have a global count. Then do the old `i++;` incrementing and when `i == totalSlides` that means you are on your last slide and you can perform whatever actions you wish.

Comment: That would great but each slide has different numbers of thumbnail so it cannot work.

Comment: Hmm, re-reading your question, so 1 slide can have multiple thumbs, and there are many slides that have many thumbs in each? If so then you could still you my theory, just scoped to each slide. Let me know if I have misinterpreted this, also if you have a public example that would help!

Comment: The slide are dynamically generated from a custom CMS I built for the client. So he may add a new page with a new slide with any possible numbers of images. Thank you by the way for your suggestion.